# DevExpress MVC .net 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-4.0, devexpress

Im just wondering if anyone has used DevExpress's MVC Extension controls successfully on .net framework 4.0 MVC 2?

All reference I see to the product seem to only support 3.5.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MVC 2 is dependent on .NET 3.5 SP1 so everything should run just fine for you in 4.0 or 3.5 SP1.